# Reading a large csv datafile with multiple lines of headerinfo into Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, import-from-csv, large-data

Does anyone have some advice how to read a comma separated data file into Matlab? The simple solutions (like dlmread, fscanf) do not seem to work, as there are multiple (10) lines of header information. The closest I got to a solution is:

```
C=textscan(datafile)
G=cell2mat(C{1,1}(34:endoffile)}) //34 is the line the data starts
V=str2num(G)
```

the problem here is that the data for instance looks like this:

```
;1.0345,937,18,763
;1.0355,947,4,652
etc.
```

When converting into the matrix all strings in the cell have to be of the same size, otherwise an error using 'vertcat' is given. If no other option, I could just delete the header in lets say notepad, but with many many files this would be a tedious job.

Answer (score 5):

[DLMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html) accepts starting row/column parameters, or alternatively a range parameter.  So if your data starts on line 10, you could try

```
V = dlmread(datafile, '', 9, 0);
```

If you prefer [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html), you can specify a number of `HeaderLines` to skip:

```
V = textscan(datafile, ..., 'HeaderLines', 10, ...);
```

Scan down to "User Configurable Options" on the documentation page for more details.